# Determine if a Qt timer trigger event is the one due to triggeredOnStart being true

Tags: qt, timer, triggers, qml

Is there some convenient way to find out, in `onTriggered()`, whether you are being called as a result of `triggeredOnStart` being  `true`, rather than as a result of the timer timing out?

The doc says

> It is sometimes desirable to trigger immediately when the timer is started; for example, to establish an initial state.

but pretty obviously this would be most useful if you can actually tell that it's the first time, so do setup.

This can clearly be done manually by setting some state variable somewhere, and changing it in onTriggered, but that is pretty cumbersome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Qt is laconic but very useful tool and particularly QML too. So you have ability to do what you want using existing facility. As for your question, you can use one of existed events, exactly as you said.

For example:

```
Timer {
    id: timer
    running: false
    interval: 1000
    triggeredOnStart: true
    onRunningChanged: {
        console.log(running)
    }
    onTriggered: {
        console.log("triggered")
    }

    Component.onCompleted: timer.running = true
}
```

**Output:**

```
qml: true
qml: triggered
qml: false
qml: triggered
```

Comment: Perfect, just the kind of thing I hoped to find, thanks!  I need to think/experiment a bit about how to use this in the case of a repeating timer: it depends on how `running` operates in that case, of course.